# Evaluating ${\Large\int} _{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)-4}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

This integral is giving me hard times, could anyone "prompt" a strategy about? I tried, resultless, parameterization and some change of variables.

$${\Large\int} _{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)-4}dx$$

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of the odd part.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin^4 x-4}dx=-\int\dfrac{1}{(1-u^2)^2-4}du\\\int\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^4 x-4}dx=\int\dfrac{du}{u^4-4}=0.25\int\dfrac{du}{u^2-2}-0.25\int\dfrac{du}{u^2+2}$$the first one is zero over a symmetric interval and for the second we have$$I=0.25\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{du}{u^2-2}-0.25\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{du}{u^2+2}=\dfrac{1}{4\sqrt 2}\ln\dfrac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt 2+1}-{\sqrt{2}\over 4}\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Thank you! Really useful

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

Following a suggestion from the comments, you can reduce your integral to$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\cos x}{\sin^4(x)-4}\,\mathrm dx.$$Now, do the substitution $\sin x=t$ and $\cos x\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$.

Comment: Thank you! Really useful

Comment: Why could you get rid of $\sin(x)$? Thanks

Comment: @Arcticmonkey $\frac{\sin x}{\sin^4(x)-4}$ is an odd function and therefore its integral on the interval $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the odd part and then set $t = \sin x$.

$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\cos x}{\sin^4(x)-4}\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{t^4-4} = \frac14\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{t^2-2} - \frac14\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{t^2+2}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you, I can